# перестал работать код с cookies после нововведений chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Есть такой код, который показывает модалку после определенного времени. После обновлений хрома - It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

Попробовал вписать атрибуты но все равно не то.

Код:

```
function setCookie(key, value, expiry) {
      var expires = new Date();
      expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (expiry * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';path=/;SameSite=None;Secure;expires=' + expires.toUTCString();  }

      function getCookie(key) {
        var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null; }

        if(getCookie('showfromcitymodal') == '-1'){
          setCookie('showfromcitymodal','1','30'); // 30 дней
          $('#fromcity').modal('show'); }
```

Кто-то может подсказать в чем ошибка? 2й день пробую разные варианты и не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

убрал лишний код и неправильное (на данный момент ибо ранее этот древний код работал) сравнение проверки существования куки.

а с SameSite и Secure, как оказалось не связано (ранее в коде их не было и работал)

вот рабочий код:

```
   function getCookie(g_name) {
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + g_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null; }
    
    function setCookie(s_name) {
     var expires = new Date();
     expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 30 дней
     document.cookie = s_name + '=shown;path=/;expires=' + expires.toUTCString() + ';secure';  }
    
     if(!getCookie("choosecity")){
       setCookie("choosecity");
       $('#fromcity').modal('show'); }
```

Comment: а чем код в ответе отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: убрал лишние куски, и неправильное сравнение было для проверки наличия куки.
код древний, ранее работал - нужно было функционал дать в модалку и определил, что она вовсе то и не вызывается теперь.. думал связано с SameSite и Secure ибо в старой версии их не было, но нет

Comment: Добавь это описание в ответ. Сейчас кажется что ответ - это просто часть вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему отключением, т.к. некоторые говорят, что сам `SameSite=None` не всегда работает в хроме.

1. chrome://flags
2. SameSite by default cookies
3. Disabled

Если кто-то решал по другому, пишите в комментарии, мне тоже интересно :)

Comment: это ведь локальное решение

Answer (score 0):

Параметр Secure указывает на то, что кук будут передаваться только по защищенному соединению - по протоколу https.

Параметр SameSite=none указывает на то, что кук будут передаваться по https, когда сайт загружается у третьих лиц, т.е. в iframe или при использовании кросс-сайтовых запросов. Так же вместе с этим параметром должен быть установлен параметр Secure.